# neo4j/everyman: how to get error messages from cypher?

Tags: php, neo4j

Am attempting to call a cypher query that I know returns an error message. Using `Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query` I'm not getting any response that would indicate that an error has been returned.

Example:

```
$client = getClient();  
$query = "<some query that will fail>";  
$q = new Everyman\Neo4j\Cypher\Query( $client, $query );  
try  
{  
    $result = $q->getResultSet();  
}  
catch( Exception $e )  
{  
    error_log( print_r( $e, true ));  
    return 1;  
}

return 0;
```

Example: delete nodes that have relationships without deleting the relationships. 
I should be seeing an exception like **Neo.DatabaseError.Transaction.CouldNotCommit**. I've tried dumping the whole result object but I'm missing something central here.

Suggestions? I'm sure this is an easy one.

Comment: Are you sure your query will fail? If you run it without the try/catch is the exception actually being thrown? If you run the same query using CURL or the Neo4j web console, does it give you the right error?

Comment: I'm running it via the neo web interface. That's where I see the above exception being generated. I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong with the API - I just don't see what.

Comment: Try to get the raw REST statement that is failing.

Comment: i am getting the same error. i do not know why please help me with it.